# How to remove the path in the import if it has an alias, automatically and throughout the project?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I don't want the project to have full paths in the imports, if it is possible to use aliases.

For example, I have import:

`import { DropDownFilters } from '../../../../../uikit/DropDownFilters'`

I want to write it as:

`'import { DropDownFilters } from uikit/DropDownFilters'`

I don't want to walk around the project manually and fix things like that, I want to configure `eslint` so that it fixes it itself or at least highlights the problems

Comment: It is unclear what your actual problem is. Please be more specific on the exact problem you are having and include an example and or error message.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution yesterday while I was talking with the senior person on our team. Here it goes:

Create a config.json file with any name (if that doesn't work use jsconfig.js, it is like a setting for a JS or a TS project)

Use the code below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

It says that all my imported files and modules are in the ./src folder.